# How to disable title in shapoint homepage?

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to hide title in home page without javascript 
Using asp code ?

Right now iam using javascript, its working but when page load it is coming and hide after total page loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS code to hide site title in SharePoint HomePage:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-core-pageTitle{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```